# Is there another way to ensure fields from other union type variants are not included?

Tags: typescript

Given this scenario

```
type Foo = {
  foo: string;
};

type Bar = {
  bar: string;
};

type MyUnion = Foo | Bar;

// ALLOWED
const x: MyUnion = { foo: "", bar: "" };
```

I would like typescript to detect that having both `foo` and `bar` in a value of type `MyUnion` is forbidden.

The two ways I know to prevent it are a) converting to a discriminating union type:

```
type Foo = {
  _type: "foo";
  foo: string;
};

type Bar = {
  _type: "bar";
  bar: string;
};

type MyUnion = Foo | Bar;

// FORBIDDEN
const x: MyUnion = { _type: "foo", foo: "", bar: "" };
```

and b) explicitly forbidding the fields of other variants to be defined

```
type Foo = {
  foo: string;
  bar?: undefined;
};

type Bar = {
  bar: string;
  foo?: undefined;
};

type MyUnion = Foo | Bar;

// FORBIDDEN
const x: MyUnion = { foo: "", bar: "" };
```

Is there another way not relying on any of these two methods?

Comment: Typo where `bar: undefined;`  should be `bar?: undefined;`

Comment: I'm confused why you want a third method; what's wrong with those two methods?  TS doesn't have *exact types* as requested in [ms/TS#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936) so I doubt there will be any method that's as simple as you presumably want.

Comment: It surprised me that the initial case is allowed and I want to find the simplest solution, but maybe this is it then